# How to calculate the volume of intersection of sphere and cylinder

Tags: integration, volume, spheres, monte-carlo

I have to calculate the volume of intersection of a sphere and a cylinder. 
The cylinder's radius is $r$ and the center point is $(r,0,0)$.
The sphere's center point is $(0,0,0)$ and the radius $2r$.

I calculated the estimated volume with Monte Carlo methods but now I have to calculate the real volume with a formula.
Is there any kind of explicit equation for this volume?

I will appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: Please show that estimated volume calculation and any and all other relevant info, please!

Comment: ok=0;
    
    for i=1:n
        x = rand(1,3);
        x = x*4*R-2*R;
        if((x(1))^2+(x(2))^2+x(3)^2-(2*R)^2 <= 0 && ((x(1)-R)/R)^2+(x(2)/R)^2-1 <= 0)
            ok=ok+1;   
        end
        
    end
    
    montecarlo_V = ok/n * (2*R)^3;

Comment: I used this to calculate the estimated, now I have to calculate the theoretical one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, draw a figure, and you will realize that the volume is given by
$$
2\iint_D \sqrt{(2r)^2-x^2-y^2}\,dx\,dy
$$
where
$$
D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2~|~(x-r)^2+y^2\leq r^2\}.
$$
I leave it to you to calculate the integral.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you give me some hints, links how can I calculate this? I'm not very good in math :(

Answer (score 0):

Let the sphere be $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 4a^2$
And the cylinder be $(x - a)^2+y^2 = a^2$
Using polar coordinates we have
$$x = r cos\theta cos\phi$$
$$y = r sin\theta cos\phi$$
$$z = r sin\phi$$
Then the equation of the sphere is r = 2a
And the cylinder $r cos\phi = 2a cos\theta$
Solving the 2 equations we have the curve of intersection $cos\phi = cos\theta$ or $\phi = \theta$
This means that for a fixed $\theta$ we have $\phi$ varies from 0 to $\theta$ and r varies from 0 to 2a and $\theta$ from 0 to $\pi$ / 2 by considering only the first quadrant.
By transforming to polar coordinates we have the volume integrant to be 
$$\frac{D(x, y, z)}{D(\theta, \phi, r)} = r^2cos\phi$$
Hence the total volume is 
$$4\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{2a}\int_0^\theta r^2cos{\phi}d{\phi}drd{\theta}$$
$$= 4\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{2a}r^2sin{\theta}drd{\theta}$$
$$= 4\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{8a^3}{3}sin{\theta}d{\theta}$$
$$= \frac{32a^3}{3}$$